# How do I check the difference in time of 2 datetime objects?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

Let's say x and y are datetime objects in Python.

How do I check:

```
if y - x is more than 30 seconds:
    print "ok, 30 seconds have passed"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following class can be used for duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances to microsecond resolution:

`class datetime.timedelta`

The following code can be used for your purposes:

```
if (y-x) >datetime.timedelta(0,30):
```

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.7 you can do:

```
if (y - x).total_seconds() > 30:
  print "ok, 30 seconds have passed"
```

or this should work:

```
if y - datetime.timedelta(seconds = 30) > x:
  print "ok, 30 seconds have passed"
```

Ref: [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to compare the two dates - it will let you test how many seconds are between them.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta would be a better link

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two `datetime` objects will produce a `datetime.timedelta` object.

These objects have a convenient attribute, `seconds`, which gives the number of seconds contained in the `timedelta`.